# Duplicate record no entered in database table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing a .ASPX page with following design

```
Firstname
Lastname
Address
City
Mobile
```

This is represented to user with labels and textboxes.

When user clicks on Save button, data is saved in SQL Server 2008 Express database table.

Table has following schema

```
RecordNo-int(PK)
Firstname-nvarchar(50)
Lastname-nvarchar(50)
Address-nvarchar(500)
City-nvarchar(50)
Mobile-nvarchar(12)
```

At the time of page loading, I also display recordno to user.

This record number is generated based on how many records are there in the table.

I get the number of records and just increment it by 1 and put it against RecordNo.

Now, if this is happening on one PC, it works fine.

First entry will be represented with RecordNo 1

and so on.

But if, there is no record in the table, and the same page is opened by 4 different users at the same time, then all will

be represented with RecordNo 1.

and then, user who first click save button, will be able to save the data perfectly.

But other three users will encounter error, because they are entering information with RecordNo 1, which is already entered.

How do i overcome this?

Each new entry should be given new and unique RecordNo.

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make RecordNo an IDENTITY(1,1) field and forget about all your logic to generate the key. IDENTITY does this for you automatically.

If you require you can call SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the record is inserted to capture the generated value.

Comment: But what if i dont want to use IDENTITY?Is there any other solution to this?I am required to display the RecordNo at the time of entry.

Comment: On SQL 2008 you can use a SEQUENCE also. You can also write your own stored procedure (there are a few around) that locks the table and stops you generating identical numbers. But you should consider how important it is for a user to see a database specific code - normally this is of no interest to the user.

Comment: If you mean at the time of entry, then start after you insert the record you use SCOPE_IDENTITY to capture the new identity value

Answer (score 0):

Why to take headache of showing the number of entries you just set the primary key column to Identity(1,1) which will increment that column value by 1 every time a new row is inserted. This is how 'n' number of user will be able to make entries concurrently.

Comment: But what if i dont want to use IDENTITY?Is there any other solution to this?I am required to display the RecordNo at the time of entry.

Comment: @Hemal Why don't you want to use IDENTITY?  It is guaranteed to be unique, even in the case of simultaneous updates, which is the situation you have.

Comment: @Vipin, I want to avoid IDENTITY, because I need to display new RecordNo on a web page at the time of new entry, so that user can identify which record no he is entering. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @Hemal But why the user needs to know at which row is he entering the record? This can be the case where the user is admin.

Answer (score 0):

Set an Identity Cloumn as :

```
RecordNo int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
```

In Identity(1,1) first 1 is Starting Value and Other is Increment Value.

Use the code below if you don't want to use Identity:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordNo ASC) AS RecordNumber,
FirstName,LastName,Address,City,Mobile from yourTableName) AS RecordNo
```

Comment: But what if i dont want to use IDENTITY?Is there any other solution to this?I am required to display the RecordNo at the time of entry.

Comment: if you don't want to use identity, then see the Updated Answer